# Duplo rail accessory compatibility with older trains

Tags: trains, duplo

[image: 6225521: Rail Accessory, No. 6]
[image: 6225516: Rail Accessory, No. 2]
[image: 6225519: Rail Accessory, No. 4]

Are the new Duplo rail accessories, like [#6225521](https://brickset.com/parts/6225521/rail-accessory-no-6) and [#6225519](https://brickset.com/parts/6225519/rail-accessory-no-4)  (appearing in, for example Duplo [#10872: Train Bridge and Tracks](https://brickset.com/sets/10872-1/Train-Bridge-and-Tracks); [#10874: Steam Train](https://brickset.com/sets/10874-1/Steam-Train); and [#10875: Cargo Train](https://brickset.com/sets/10875-1/Cargo-Train)) compatible with older Duplo trains (for example, [#10507: My First Train Set](https://brickset.com/sets/10507-1/My-First-Train-Set) and [#10508: Deluxe Train Set](https://brickset.com/sets/10508-1/Deluxe-Train-Set))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Physically, these parts are compatible. They simply rest in between the rails. Various elements have made use of the space between the rails for years, such as points:

[image: Duplo point]

Older trains don't have any way to understand the function elements and respond accordingly, but they won't derail or anything like that.